# convert str(list) to list using json module

Tags: python, json

I get a ValueError when loading a stringified list using str with json.loads.
E.g.

```
l = ['a', 'b']
l_str = str(l)
l_loaded = json.loads(l_str)
```

However, this works:

```
x = '["a", "b"]'
x_loaded = json.loads(x)
```

Why is this?

Comment: Because a stringified list is not valid JSON…!?

Comment: But then why is '["a", "b"]' valid json and loadable with json.loads(x)?

Comment: Because that *is* valid JSON. Specifically, JSON requires `"` quotes, not `'` quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try printing out the value of `l_str`. You'll see

```
['a', 'b']
```

not the

```
["a", "b"]
```

that you're comparing it to.

And even if this happened to work, it's not a good idea to muddle formats like this. What if someone came along and gave you the list `[None, object(), open("/usr/bin/python3", "r")]`? *That* is definitely not going to be valid JSON when stringified.

Answer (score 3):

JSON syntax is not Python syntax. JSON requires double quotes for its strings.

Answer (score 3):

Because str() uses simple quotes as default, and JSON requires double quotes.

For more details about str(), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109030/how-does-strlist-work)